# Can I run a jupyter notebook with an R kernel from a jupyter notebook with a python kernel?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have some R code to update a database stored in `update_db.ipynb`. When I try to `%run update_db.ipynb` from a jupyter notebook with a python kernel, I get an error

```
File "<ipython-input-8-815efb9473c5>", line 14
    city_weather <- function(start,end,airports){
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Looks like it thinks that `update_db.ipynb` is written in python.  Can I specify which kernel to use when I use `%run`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is not due to the kernel selected. Your command `%run` is made to run python *only*, but it has to be a script, not a notebook. You can check in details the [ipython magic commands](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run)

For your use case I would suggest to install both python and R kernel in jupyter. Then you can use the magic cell command `%%R` to select to run R kernel for a cell inside the python notebook. Source :[this great article on jupyter - tip 19](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/)

Other solution is to put your R code in an R script, and then execute it from a jupyter notebook. For this you can run a bash command from a jupyter notebook that will execute the script

```
!R path/to/script.r
```